# Noobish query, but how do i get the actual .exe file of my finished Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

so basically i have finished a project and want to create the .exe file for transporting to another computer for testing purposes.

I am aware that there is a .exe file in the debug area of my application, but it doesn't have the icon which my program has in the task bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a release build, with default project settings, your executable will appear in

```
<projectdir>\Win32\Release
```

for a 32 bit build. For a 64 bit build it will be in

```
<projectdir>\Win64\Release
```

The mismatching icon is probably just that the shell has caches a previous version of your executable's icon. Copy the executable file to another location and you will see the icon you expect. Or restart your computer.

Comment: Thanks alot :D I looked back into my \Debug  and saw the correct icon after closing my application